# Processing attrbutes issue

Tags: r

I'm trying to write function which take columns attributes and transform them into appropriate strings.

My data has variable labels (description of column), variable names, type (factor, numeric, character), and defined factor levels (f.e. 1=yes, 2=no). I'd like to use function which generates string which contains all info in appropriate order:

```
Q B
Q [varname] vallab
T S #type
R yes
R no
Q E
```

I wrote function like this:

```
WriteQ<-function(VarLab,VarName,Responses,VarType) {
  cond<-sapply(VarType, switch,
               factor="T S\n",
               numeric="T I\n",
               character="T C\n")
  mystr<-paste0("Q B\nQ [",VarName,"] ", VarLab, "\n",cond,"L0L2\n",paste("R",Responses, collapse =  "\n"),"\nQ E")
  return(mystr)
}
```

And trying to call this like:

```r
attributes(data)$qps<-WriteQ(attributes(data)$variable.labels,
                               attributes(data)$names,
                               unlist(lapply(data, attr, "levels")),
                               unlist(lapply(data, class)))
```

While VarLab, VarName and VarType works fine, I have a problem with Responses. 
It prints all levels form entire dataframe in each section. How I should pass list of levels separately for each column?

Structure of file:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2), q23 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("yes", 
"no", "don't know"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(1L, 
1L), .Label = c("male", "female"), class = "factor"), age = c(33, 
44)), row.names = 1:2, variable.labels = c("id", "Do you like flowers?", 
"Select gender...", "How old are you?"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you do `dput(data)`, so we can get a copy of it?

Comment: Hard to know without a good example, but I think you probably need to work on that paste()  by trying it on a single column until you get it the way you need it.  You may in fact want to preprocess that before feeding it to your function. Or make a separate function that you call from the WriteQ function. That will be cleaner and easier to test.

Comment: What is `L0L2` (besides a static string)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot:

```r
WriteQ <- function(VarLab, VarName, Responses, VarType) {
  Qs <- sprintf("Q [%s] %s", VarName, VarLab)
  Ts <- sapply(VarType, switch,
               factor="T S",
               numeric="T I",
               character="T C")
  Rs <- lapply(Responses, function(r) sprintf("R %s L0L2", r))
  QEs <- rep("Q E", length(VarLab))
  out <- Map(c, Qs, Ts, Rs, QEs)
  out
  # setNames(out, VarName)
  # setNames(lapply(out, paste, collapse = "\n"), VarName)
  # unlist(out, use.names = FALSE)
  # paste(unlist(out), collapse = "\n")
}
```

The default output is:

```r
out
# $`Q [id] id`
# [1] "Q [id] id" "T I"       "Q E"      
# $`Q [q23] Do you like flowers?`
# [1] "Q [q23] Do you like flowers?" "T S"                         
# [3] "R yes L0L2"                   "R no L0L2"                   
# [5] "R don't know L0L2"            "Q E"                         
# $`Q [gender] Select gender...`
# [1] "Q [gender] Select gender..." "T S"                        
# [3] "R male L0L2"                 "R female L0L2"              
# [5] "Q E"                        
# $`Q [age] How old are you?`
# [1] "Q [age] How old are you?" "T I"                     
# [3] "Q E"
```

Alternative output formats, depending on your needs:

```r
setNames(out, VarName)
# $id
# [1] "Q [id] id" "T I"       "Q E"      
# $q23
# [1] "Q [q23] Do you like flowers?" "T S"                         
# [3] "R yes L0L2"                   "R no L0L2"                   
# [5] "R don't know L0L2"            "Q E"                         
# $gender
# [1] "Q [gender] Select gender..." "T S"                        
# [3] "R male L0L2"                 "R female L0L2"              
# [5] "Q E"                        
# $age
# [1] "Q [age] How old are you?" "T I"                     
# [3] "Q E"                     

setNames(lapply(out, paste, collapse = "\n"), VarName)
# $id
# [1] "Q [id] id\nT I\nQ E"
# $q23
# [1] "Q [q23] Do you like flowers?\nT S\nR yes L0L2\nR no L0L2\nR don't know L0L2\nQ E"
# $gender
# [1] "Q [gender] Select gender...\nT S\nR male L0L2\nR female L0L2\nQ E"
# $age
# [1] "Q [age] How old are you?\nT I\nQ E"

unlist(out, use.names = FALSE)
#  [1] "Q [id] id"                    "T I"                         
#  [3] "Q E"                          "Q [q23] Do you like flowers?"
#  [5] "T S"                          "R yes L0L2"                  
#  [7] "R no L0L2"                    "R don't know L0L2"           
#  [9] "Q E"                          "Q [gender] Select gender..." 
# [11] "T S"                          "R male L0L2"                 
# [13] "R female L0L2"                "Q E"                         
# [15] "Q [age] How old are you?"     "T I"                         
# [17] "Q E"                         

paste(unlist(out), collapse = "\n")
# [1] "Q [id] id\nT I\nQ E\nQ [q23] Do you like flowers?\nT S\nR yes L0L2\nR no L0L2\nR don't know L0L2\nQ E\nQ [gender] Select gender...\nT S\nR male L0L2\nR female L0L2\nQ E\nQ [age] How old are you?\nT I\nQ E"
```

Comment: thanks it works when there are equal number of attributes, however not for all variables labels, and responses exist. Thanks anyway it gave me good view on direction I should go.

Comment: If you edit your question with a sample of data that does *not* work, then I may be able to fix whatever is wrong.